# select dropdown button with bootstrap: cannot find pressed css

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select, bootstrap-selectpicker

ok, this may sound pretty easy, yet i cannot find the css responsible for the  blue border in this select dropdown button by bootstrap

[image: blue border at button]
does anyone have a clue how i can get the class in the css file?

```
    <form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">
  <!--<fieldset>-->
    <select class="selectpicker" name="category">
      <option value="AFR">Afrika</option>
      <option value="CA">Amerika (Mitte) & Karibik</option>
      <option value="NA">Amerika (Norden)</option>
    </select><br/>
    <select class="selectpicker" name="choices" id="choices">
      <option value="ae">Äthiopien</option>
      <option value="bo-mo-si">Botswana, Mosambik & Simbabwe</option>
      <option value="ma-ma-sey">Madagaskar, Mauritius & Seychellen</option>
      <option value="nam">Namibia</option>
      <option value="na">Nordafrika (Küste)</option>
      <option value="na-l">Nordafrika (Landesinneres) & Sahara</option>
      <option value="ka">Kamerun</option>
      <option value="ke">Kenia & Tansania</option>
      <option value="ma">Mali</option>
      <option value="ru-ug">Ruanda & Uganda</option>
      <option value="sa">Südafrika</option>
      <option value="wa">Westafrika</option>
    </select>
 <!-- </fieldset>-->
</form>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/49FK9/90/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `outline: none` for `.dropdown-toggle` and `.dropdown li a`.

```
.demoForm .bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus,
.demoForm .bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

```css
.demoForm .bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus,
.demoForm .bootstrap-select.btn-group .dropdown-menu li a {
    outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://the-backpacker.net/scripts/js/bootstrap-select.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://the-backpacker.net/scripts/css/bootstrap-select.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form action="#" method="post" id="demoForm" class="demoForm">
  <!--<fieldset>-->
  <select class="selectpicker" name="category">
    <option value="AFR">Afrika</option>
    <option value="CA">Amerika (Mitte) & Karibik</option>
    <option value="NA">Amerika (Norden)</option>
  </select><br/>
  <select class="selectpicker" name="choices" id="choices">
    <option value="ae">Äthiopien</option>
    <option value="bo-mo-si">Botswana, Mosambik & Simbabwe</option>
    <option value="ma-ma-sey">Madagaskar, Mauritius & Seychellen</option>
    <option value="nam">Namibia</option>
    <option value="na">Nordafrika (Küste)</option>
    <option value="na-l">Nordafrika (Landesinneres) & Sahara</option>
    <option value="ka">Kamerun</option>
    <option value="ke">Kenia & Tansania</option>
    <option value="ma">Mali</option>
    <option value="ru-ug">Ruanda & Uganda</option>
    <option value="sa">Südafrika</option>
    <option value="wa">Westafrika</option>
  </select>
  <!-- </fieldset>-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add outline:none to `.dropdown-menu`.

```
.dropdown-menu a:focus { outline: none; }
```